# Android take image path from text file

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, text-files

I have a text file in my assets folder that contains the details of an outlet like:

McDonald's | Any McDonald's outlet| Applicable to any lunch meal set| Buy 1 get 1 free| 1 Aug - 31 Aug| RM 32.00| RM 16.00| icon_nandos.png

And I split them and store in the string array. But I couldn't set the image from the 7th array item (which is icon_nandos.png)

```
 try{
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(this.getAssets().open("food_catalog.txt")));
        while ((food = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
            if (!food.equals("")) {
                String[] foodInfo = food.split("\\|");

                    tv.setText(foodInfo[0] + "\n" + foodInfo[1] + "\n" + foodInfo[2] + "\n" + foodInfo[3] + "\n" + foodInfo[4] + "\n" + foodInfo[5] + "\n" + foodInfo[6] + "\n" + foodInfo[7] + "\n");
                   img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(foodInfo[7]));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried several ways of setting the images like setImageURI but the image still wouldn't show. Am I doing anything wrong? Many of the sources online doesn't refer to what I am doing.

**Image and text file location**

[image: Image and text file loacation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to open Image file also via `getAssets()`.

Try as below

```
InputStream inStream= getAssets().open(foodInfo[7]);
Drawable drw = Drawable.createFromStream(inStream, null);
img.setImageDrawable(drw);
inStream.close();
```

> Assuming that your `foodInfo[7]` gives you the name "icon_nandos.png"

Comment: I have used your suggestion but it doesnt work unless i change the `InputStream inStream= getAssets().open(foodInfo[7]);` to `.open("nandos.png");` I have also tried made it foodInfo[7].toString

Comment: that do mean that your splitting is not working properly. Check it via log or debug.

Comment: It should gets the right image path since when i print the foodInfo[7] it shows nandos.png

Comment: Try foodInfo[7].toString().trim();

Answer (score 0):

I am able to retrieve the image by trimming foodInfo[7]

Use :

```html
  img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open
                            (foodInfo[7].trim())));
```

instead of

```html
 img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(foodInfo[7]));
```